# How to traverse entire JSON structure while appending 3 elements to a dictionary (or any other structure) that meet criteria?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Got a confusing json object.

I have list of dictionaries with below JSON tree structure with an example included.

I am trying to traverse the tree and pull out 3 pieces of information based on the following logic:

1. for every 'document_tree' array in every object in the list, if 'type'
   starts with 'H', and if 'child' is present, then go to
   into 'child' array, and check if the next 'type' is equal to 'HTML'.

   - if 'type' in 'child' is equal to 'HTML' then concat the strings from 'value' of all the elements where 'type' elements equals 'HTML' while tracking the string of the 'id' of every 'value' being concated for every 'type' equal to 'HTML' and append it to the string of 'value' from the parent element. Open to any sort of
   - if 'type' in 'child' is not equal to 'HTML' ,then only record the string of 'value' in parent element, with "id" equal to empty string, if "id" is not present in element. If it is present, then record that value.

The code should return back data like this, and im open to any format or type to return back (dict, dataframe, etc). I will say that the data will eventually go into pandas, so any data format to do that easily would be appreciated. FYI I couldnt get the ID column to align:

```
   main_text                     sub_text                                          id
0  Dog, facts and photos
1  Domestic dog                  mostly kept as pets                        090b4d91 
2  Dog - Wikipedia               
3  Dog                           Domesticated canid species "\"Pooch\" For other \"Doggy\" Gmelin, 1792.       c6edc846,e1689ad9,0c95357e
```

My code currently is not traversing the full structure and not pulling out 'value' string where 'type' is not equal to 'HTML' of the parent and not grabbing the IDs, bc I dont know how to implement this and how to structure the data. The code is able to grab some parent and child values.

code:

```
def extract_values_from_child_array(data):
    results = {}
    for d in data:
        if "document_tree" in d:
            for t in d["document_tree"]:
                if t["type"].startswith("H"):
                    current_type = t["value"]
                    if "child" in t:
                        for c in t["child"]:
                            if c["type"].startswith("H"):
                                current_type = c["value"]
                                if current_type not in results:
                                    results[current_type] = ""
                            elif c["type"] == "HTML":
                                if current_type not in results:
                                    results[current_type] = ""
                                results[current_type] += c["value"]
                            if "child" in c:
                                for gc in c["child"]:
                                    if gc["type"] == "HTML":
                                        if current_type not in results:
                                            results[current_type] = ""
                                        results[current_type] += gc["value"]
    return results







results1 = extract_values_from_child_array(data1)
```

```
 tree: 
    ─  (array)
       └─  (object)
          ├─ "id" (string)
          ├─ "key" (string)
          ├─ "number" (number)
          ├─ "result_title" (string)
          ├─ "result_url" (string)
          ├─ "document_tree" (array)
          │  └─  (object)
          │     ├─ "type" (string)
          │     ├─ "value" (string)
          │     ├─ "child" (array)
          │     │  └─  (object)
          │     │     ├─ "type" (string)
          │     │     ├─ "value" (string)
          │     │     ├─ "child" (array)
          │     │     │  └─  (object)
          │     │     │     ├─ "type" (string)
          │     │     │     ├─ "key" (string)
          │     │     │     ├─ "id" (string)
          │     │     │     └─ "value" (string)
          │     │     ├─ "id" (string)
          │     │     └─ "key" (string)
          │     ├─ "id" (string)
          │     └─ "key" (string)
          ├─ "featured_image_url" (string)
          ├─ "hidden" (number)
          ├─ "domain" (string)
          └─ "result_preview_text" (string)
    
    example:
    
     [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "key": "example_1",
            "number": 1,
            "result_title": "Result Title 1",
            "result_url": "https://example.com/result_1",
            "document_tree": [
              {
                "type": "H1",
                "value": "Dog, facts and photos",
                "child": [
                  {
                    "type": "H1",
                    "value": "Domestic dog",
                    "child": [
                      {
                        "type": "HTML",
                        "key": "090b4d91",
                        "id": "090b4d91",
                        "value": "mostly kept as pets"
                      }
                    ],
                    "id": "1",
                    "key": "key_1"
                  }
                ],
                "featured_image_url": "https://example.com/featured_image_1.jpg",
                "hidden": 0,
                "domain": "example.com",
                "result_preview_text": "Result Preview Text 1"
              },
              {
                "id": "2",
                "key": "example_2",
                "number": 2,
                "result_title": "Result Title 2",
                "result_url": "https://example.com/result_2",
                "document_tree": [
                  {
                    "type": "H1",
                    "value": "Dog - Wikipedia",
                    "child": [
                      {
                        "type": "H1",
                        "value": "Dog",
                        "child": [
                          {
                            "type": "HTML",
                            "key": "c6edc846",
                            "id": "c6edc846",
                            "value": "Domesticated canid species"
                          },
                          {
                            "type": "HTML",
                            "key": "e1689ad9",
                            "id": "e1689ad9",
                            "value": "\"Pooch\" For other ."
                          },
                          {
                            "type": "HTML",
                            "key": "0c95357e",
                            "id": "0c95357e",
                            "value": "\"Doggy\" Gmelin, 1792"
                          }
                        ],
                        "featured_image_url": "https://example.com/featured_image_2.jpg",
                        "hidden": 1,
                        "domain": "example.com",
                        "result_preview_text": "Result Preview Text 2"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

Comment: Your example might not be correct. Notice that you have "example_2" under the array of "document_tree" of "example_1". I suppose "example_2" should be at the same level as "example_1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now (2023-02-23 22:05 PST), I think the example provided in the question is not correct. The answer below is based on the following example. Notice that in the following example, "example_1" and "example_2" are on the same level, whereas in the question, "example_2" is contained within "example_1".

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "key": "example_1",
    "number": 1,
    "result_title": "Result Title 1",
    "result_url": "https://example.com/result_1",
    "document_tree": [
      {
        "type": "H1",
        "value": "Dog, facts and photos",
        "child": [
          {
            "type": "H1",
            "value": "Domestic dog",
            "child": [
              {
                "type": "HTML",
                "key": "090b4d91",
                "id": "090b4d91",
                "value": "mostly kept as pets"
              }
            ],
            "id": "1",
            "key": "key_1"
          }
        ],
        "featured_image_url": "https://example.com/featured_image_1.jpg",
        "hidden": 0,
        "domain": "example.com",
        "result_preview_text": "Result Preview Text 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "key": "example_2",
    "number": 2,
    "result_title": "Result Title 2",
    "result_url": "https://example.com/result_2",
    "document_tree": [
      {
        "type": "H1",
        "value": "Dog - Wikipedia",
        "child": [
          {
            "type": "H1",
            "value": "Dog",
            "child": [
              {
                "type": "HTML",
                "key": "c6edc846",
                "id": "c6edc846",
                "value": "Domesticated canid species"
              },
              {
                "type": "HTML",
                "key": "e1689ad9",
                "id": "e1689ad9",
                "value": "\"Pooch\" For other ."
              },
              {
                "type": "HTML",
                "key": "0c95357e",
                "id": "0c95357e",
                "value": "\"Doggy\" Gmelin, 1792"
              }
            ],
            "featured_image_url": "https://example.com/featured_image_2.jpg",
            "hidden": 1,
            "domain": "example.com",
            "result_preview_text": "Result Preview Text 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Suppose the correction made to the example is valid, a possible solution is shown below (see the docstring for details in recursion logic).

```py
from typing import Dict, Tuple
import pandas as pd

df_dict = {
    'main_text': [],
    'sub_text': [],
    'id': [],
}

def process_node(node: Dict) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    """Process each parent and child node.

    The logic is that if the node's type is HTML, it must be a left node. We
    simply return its value and ID.

    If the node's type starts with "H", it might contain HTML children or not.
    Regardless, we process its children and get their values and IDs.

    If the children are HTML, we record values and IDs in local arrays.
    Otherwise, we ignore them.

    Eventually, we concatenate the values and IDs, and supply them, along with
    the current node's value to df_dict.

    :param node: a node in document tree
    :type node: Dict
    :return: (value, ID) of an HTML node. Otherwise, ('', '') as dummy values.
    :rtype: Tuple[str, str]
    """
    if node.get('type', '') == 'HTML':
        return node['value'], node['id']

    val_list = []
    id_list = []
    if node.get('type', '').startswith('H'):        
        for child in node.get('child', []):
            child_val, child_id = process_node(child)
            if child['type'] == 'HTML':
                val_list.append(child_val)
                id_list.append(child_id)
        df_dict['main_text'].append(node.get('value', ''))
        df_dict['sub_text'].append(' '.join(val_list))
        df_dict['id'].append(','.join(id_list))
    return '', ''  # return dummy values
    

for top_object in data:
    for root in top_object['document_tree']:
        process_node(root)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)

# display
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
               main_text                                                             sub_text                          id
0           Domestic dog                                                  mostly kept as pets                    090b4d91
1  Dog, facts and photos                                                                                                 
2                    Dog  Domesticated canid species "Pooch" For other . "Doggy" Gmelin, 1792  c6edc846,e1689ad9,0c95357e
3        Dog - Wikipedia
```